# Add individual ID to every occurrence of h2 in var

Tags: php

I have a $text string with the formatted html inside:

```
<h2>heading 1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 3</h2>
<p>something</p>
```

I want to add now an individual id to every h2 heading:

```
<h2 id="1">heading 1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2 id="2">heading 2</h2>
```

etc.

How can I do this automatically in PHP? I think I need to loop it and plus an $i. I tried str_replace, but I think it isn't the right approach!

```
$text = str_replace("<h2>", '<h2 id=\"$i\">', $text);
```

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Why you creates HTML blocks in PHP (MVC)? Why you need IDs (CSS context selectors)? In your code attempt is undefined `$i` variable (and yes, your code can't work, it replace all `<h2>` elements - set IDs when you create this HTML markup - if you don't want to do it better in template).

Comment: I need the IDs to get my auto generated table of contents to work! I know that the code isn't working, but I am not getting the right approach. Maybe preg_replace in a loop?

Comment: PHP has functions for DOM manipulation. Then you're able to iterate over `H2` in a loop and modify them (add ID attribute). https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Can be done with preg_replace_callback without a loop - by using a counter variable passed into the callback function via reference, so that it can be incremented from in there: https://3v4l.org/8NXZc (But that you should rather not manipulate HTML using regex, still stands. Although in such a trivial case, I'd might make an exception as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution will use `strpos` to loop on all matches and `preg_replace` because it allows us to limit the number of replaces :

```php
    public  function setTagsId(String $string)
    {
       $i = 0;
        while (strpos($string, '<h2>') !== false)
        {
            $string = preg_replace('/<h2>/', '<h2 id='.$i++.'>', $string, 1);
        }
        return $string;
    }

$string = "<h2>heading 1</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<p>something</p>
<h2>heading 3</h2>
<p>something</p>";

echo setTagsId($string);
```